# Another DLL File which includes headers for sqlite?

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, sqlite

I am looking for an alternative to sqlite3.dll - is there any file on a typical system or any other file at all that includes sqlite calls? I am looking for a DLL file. I know that mozilla browser bundle used to come with a file called mozsqlite3.dll which included the calls but now it appears to have vanished from their bundle for some unknown and undocumented reason? Is there anything similar in the mozilla bundle that includes a file similar to that?

So that when I do something like

`HMODULE lib0 = LoadLibraryA("sqlite3.dll"); // file`

I can access the contents of the dll without actually having to bundle it with my game?

I want to ship my game with no dependancies, just the .exe files alone. Is there any way I can utilize another file similar to sqlite3.dll which may include the headers for the sqlite3 API calls? mozsqlite3.dll in mozilla bundle used to be an alternative, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't recommend depending on another software. Users might not have Firefox installed or you might run into version problems with later versions of Firefox packaging a modified SQLite implementation.

If you are reluctant to ship an additional `.dll` file with your program I recommend you to link SQLite itself statically into your executable. This way you will have full control over your SQLite and the users will use the same version that you thoroughly tested.

To link a SQLite statically you have to download the SQLite amalgamation sources and compile yourself as a static library with Visual Studio, and add the resulting `.lib` file as the dependency of the project. [Tutorial with images here](https://code.google.com/p/sqlitebot/wiki/VisualStudio)

Comment: If I link the sqlite dll file statically, what do you mean by that? How can I do that with msvc++ ? As right now I am just linking the library. But I need to incorporate a dll, if I download the dll and put it inside my project folder then LoadLibraryA like that I wont need to ship it with my game? That is what you mean by linking it statically?

Comment: @user3251225 No. With static linking, all the SQLite code will reside in the `.exe` file. No `.dll`s.

Comment: But the reason I need to load the library is because if I dont I wont be able to get the procaddress of it and my exe file is flagged as a malicious program by anti virus products.

So I thought an alternative would be to loadlibrary ( sqlite3.dll ) then getprocaddress and assign it to another variable and use it from there. But nowadays if I am reading a local file from the system of another user with my exe the Antivirus will flag my program as a VIRUS!

Comment: You do not use getprocaddress with a static library at all. You just use it like any other class that is in your application.

Comment: GetProcAddress() requires the dll in the first parameter. And the function you are calling in the second parameter though.

Comment: There is no dll or GetProcAddress() with static linking.

Comment: @user3251225 forget `.dll`s. You can just use SQLite functions like your own functions after static linking. I've updated my answer with a tutorial.